# ExtJS's XmlReader field mapping not work

Tags: xml, extjs

I updated this with as you suggested  it doesnt seem to run with the updated mapping  either..doesnt seem to get this Ext.data.XmlReader's  field mapping to work.

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.grid.*'
]);

    Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.define('Book',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            // set up the fields mapping into the xml doc
            // The first needs mapping, the others are very basic
            'Time', 'UserID', 'Type', 'Description','val0'
        ]
    });


        // create the Data Store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Book',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            // load using HTTP
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'audit-v2.xml',
            // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                // records will have an "Item" tag
                //record: 'rows',
               // idProperty: 'ASIN',
                //totalRecords: '@total'
                 root: 'Root',
                 record: 'AuditTrail'
            }
        }
    });


    // create the grid
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {text: "Time", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'Time', sortable: true},
            {text: "UserId", width: 180, dataIndex: 'UserId', sortable: true},
            {text: "Type", width: 115, dataIndex: 'Type', sortable: true},
            {text: "Description", width: 100, dataIndex: 'Description', sortable: true}
            {text: "Value", width: 100, dataIndex: 'Value', sortable: true}
        ],
        renderTo:'example-grid',
        width: 540,
        height: 200
    });
});
```

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Root>
    <AuditTrail>
      <Time>2012-01-10 09:27:30 (GMT-05:00)</Time>
      <UserID>DX</UserID>
      <Type>FY [REC]</Type>
      <Description>Server: wamp</Description>
      <val0>1</val0>
    </AuditTrail>
    <AuditTrail>
      <Time>2012-01-10 09:27:30 (GMT-05:00)</Time>
      <UserID>DX</UserID>
      <Type>FY [REC]</Type>
      <Description>Server:tomcat</Description>
      <val0>1</val0>
    </AuditTrail>
    <AuditTrail>
      <Time>2012-01-10 09:27:30 (GMT-05:00)</Time>
      <UserID>DX</UserID>
      <Type>FY [REC]</Type>
      <Description>Server: apache</Description>
      <val0>1</val0>
    </AuditTrail>
</Root>
```

It doesnt seem to be loading the xml

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `record` property of the reader one level too high. In your case, I believe it would be best to set `root` to `Root` and `record` to `AuditTrail`. Also, on your `Book` model, you should change the `mapping` of your `time` field to not do a relative query, i.e., your record field will be `AuditTrail`, so you don't need to drill down a level in the query:

```
    // ...

    Ext.define('Book',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['Time', 'UserID', 'Type', 'Description','val0']
    });

    // ...

    proxy: {
        // load using HTTP
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'audit-v2.xml',
        // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'Root',
            record: 'AuditTrail'
        }
    }

    // ...
```

Your store is expecting data indexes to be at the level of `AuditTrail` elements, that is why I mentioned you should set `record` to `AuditTrail`.

Comment: I updated it accordign to your example the mapping doesnt seem to run.. is there something else its missing?

Comment: I was a little confused by the question in your previous comment. Could you rephrase it? :)

Comment: Your example worked thanks a lot :). How do i add jsonp feed feed to to populate the table

Comment: jsonp means that you are getting executable javascript back from the server, so change your `proxy` type from `ajax` to `jsonp`. See [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP) for more details.